# Why is there an "y" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I encountered this while reading *Astérix*. The characters are caught in a thunderstorm in the night and the forest goes pitch black in the rain, and Obélix says "On n'y voit plus rien et il pleut!"

I know this translates approximately to "We can't see anything anymore and it's raining!" but I'm not sure why there's an *y*.

Comment: Note that even when we wouldn't bother to refer back to the current location in English, French often uses that pronoun (much as *en* will show up in somewhat vague reference to whatever facts went before).

Comment: See below my other comment, I think the location meaning of this _y_ is weakening. I think it is possible to say _je n'y vois plus rien_, without any context, just to mean _I'm blind_, without making reference to any specific location.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The other answers [have already noted](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25087/949) that the *y* there is originally about a location. I'd like to point out the difference with and without that *y*.

The sentence *je n'y vois rien* means that something is preventing you from seeing anything around you, be it darkness, heavy rain, blindness... and has become set in that meaning.

> ―Il fait complètement noir ici, je n'y vois rien !

*Je ne vois rien* can be used in the same way, but will more often mean that you *can* see your surroundings, but you don't see anything relevant to the current situation in there.

> ―On doit partir, mais j'ai l'impression d'oublier quelque chose...
>   ―Non, je ne vois rien. *[Je ne vois aucun objet qu'on doive emporter]*

Answer (score 8):

In this case, it replaces the location "here". It could be replaced by "On ne voit plus rien et il pleut **ici** !"
"We don't see anything and it rains **here**!"

Comment: Quand j'ai vu cette réponse, je me suis demandé si ce _y_ désignait vraiment un lieu. Il est possible que _y voir quelque chose_ soit, ou soit en train de devenir, une expression figée, où le _y_ perd son sens de lieu, à mon avis. _Je n'y vois rien_ peut signifier le lieu, mais aussi peut simplement être une expression, sans mettre l'accent sur un lieu.

Comment: Unrelated question, would it not be "cet *y*" rather than "ce *y*" since the word begins with a vowel?

Comment: @Aerovistae - hmmm ... you may be right. I can't change the comment anymore, but I think you are right.

Comment: More information on Wiktionnaire: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/y#Pronom_personnel_1

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure whether that *y* carries a lot of real meaning or not. It can carry a meaning of *location*, the *y* referring to a location understood from the context.

But it can also be perceived as a fixed expression, as is *je n'y vois plus rien* to mean *I'm blind*. In reverso, *n'y voir que du feu* for example, is given as synonym for *ne rien voir* directly, I think the meaning of location for that *y* can be quite weak in some contexts.

It would also be common in familiar language to say *j'y vois rien* to just mean *je ne vois rien* without necessarily having in mind a location.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why there is a *y* is that it replaces the location of where it happens.

You could also write the sentence like this:

> On ne voit plus rien *ici*(Location), et il pleut.

So the Location is replaced by a *y*, which is possible in the French language and is often used to answer questions:

Example:

> Tu vas aller *en France*?
>
> Oui, je vais *y* aller.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!